# How to select the row Id from custom formatter?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid, free-jqgrid

I am trying to get the selected row ID when I click on the icon and/or link from a custom formatter but I am not able to get it, As soon as I click on the icon nothing happen (you can see it on the Fiddle). This is how the code I am working on looks like:

```
  $.fn.fmatter.customActionsFormatter = function(cellValue, options, rowData) {
    return '<a href="#" class="delete_row" title="Delete selected row"><span class="fa fa-fw fa-trash-o delete_row" data-id="' + rowData.Id + '"></span></a>';
  };


  $(".delete_row").click(function() {
    var rowid = $("#list").jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow');

    alert(rowid);
  });
```

Why is this not working?

I have created a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/reynierpm/rmo2370r/4/) showing the issue. Just select one and try to click the icon you'll see how nothing happen

Comment: which icon you are talking about the reload ?

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam no, the delete one on each row

Comment: wrap the click binding inside `$(document).ready()` and it will work

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/buttflattery/rmo2370r/6/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use event delegation,

Taken from Jquery Learning Center https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

> Event delegation allows us to attach a single event listener, to a
>   parent element, that will fire for all descendants matching a
>   selector, whether those descendants exist now or are added in the
>   future.

```
$(document).on('click', '#list .delete_row', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var rowid = $("#list").jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow');
    alert(rowid);
})
```

As .delete_row icon is created in the custom formatter callback (and therefore appended with Javascript) the .delete_row elements you are looking for don't exists yet at the time you bind your events(They will exists when the jqgrid will finish rendering and the customFormatter triggered)

Answer (score 0):

You shoul use "on" instead of "click" to bind events.

```
$(".delete_row").on('click', function() {
  var rowid = $("#list").jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow');

  alert(rowid);
});
```

Their difference:

- "on" can be bound to dynamic elements.
- "click" only bind created elements.

Comment: I already tried that and is not the issue, either way here is an [updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/reynierpm/rmo2370r/5/) showing how is not working either

Comment: I changed your JS code and it works now: https://jsfiddle.net/rmo2370r/11/

Answer (score 0):

you need to wrap the `click` binding inside the `$(document).ready()` as there are no elements detected when the script tries to bind the `click` on the elements of class `.delete_row`, I know you just overlooked it, it happens.

see [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/buttflattery/rmo2370r/10/)